# Ruby short IF even shorter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some code:

```
<%= name ? name : 'no name' %>
```

So it prints the name, and if there is no name it prints 'no name'.
Since I still have to write two times the variable name I was wondering if there's an even shorter way?

If variable, then print it, else print something else.

Comment: The accepted answer is fine for one-offs, but if this is a common pattern, I'd write either a helper or some sort of wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. Try this one

```
<%= name.presence || 'no name' %>
```

If `name` is empty this expression evaluates to `'no name'`, otherwise to the `name`'s value.

Note that `presence` is a rails method.

As someone pointed out, if you want to print `'no name'` only if `name` is `nil` (or `false`, even if that's probably not the case) this is enough

```
<%= name || 'no name' %>
```

otherwise, if you want to print `'no name'` even if `name` is a blank string my original answer does the trick

Comment: Or simply `name || 'no name'` in OP's case because they don't seem to be treating `''` as nil .... in many cases it's safe to treat `''` as nil but not always ...

Comment: Yes, this code (with `presence`) is doing something slightly different.